# How to prevent loading form automatically

Tags: .net, vb.net

I use a forms application. When I start it, the main form automatically start, this means that also the class is automatically created.

Is there any way that I can do this manually like the following or is the first form of a form application always initialized from the start?

```
gMainForm = New MainForm
gMainForm.Show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Application Framework enabled in your project properties then yes, the startup form will be automatically created and displayed.  You can hook into the startup process and do things before that happens or exit the app without it happening but you can't have the app run and not have the startup form shown.

What you can do is disable the Application Framework and then write your own `Main` method.  In that method you can choose to call `Application.Run` if and when you want and, if you do call it, you can pass a custom `ApplicationContext` instead.  [Here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?636812-Formless-Tray-Application&highlight=)'s an example of the latter.  Here's the `Main` method from that example, written in a module that I added myself:

```
Module Program

    Public Sub Main()
        Application.Run(New TrayApplicationContext)
    End Sub

End Module
```

In that case, `TrayApplicationContext` is a class that inherits `ApplicationConext`.  `Application.Run` is what creates the message pump and it requires either a form or a application context.  In this particular case, the `TrayApplicationConext` contains a `TrayApplicationManager`, which is a component that displays a `NotifyIcon` and allows forms to be displayed from there.

Comment: A tray application would be the best for my purpose. I tried already, but I got problems with the custom ApplicationContext and async code parts.

Comment: I must have missed where you explained that in your question.  The answer I have provided is a solution to the question you asked, so it should be accepted.  If you have another question about how to create an appropriate `ApplicationContext` then you should start a new thread and provide all the information relevant to that.

Comment: I did not mean it bad, and accept your answer. I only mentioned it.

Comment: That's fine. I wasn't accusing you of anything. I was just suggesting how you should proceed from the situation as it is.